# Is there a PHP equivalent to the C# summary tag?

Tags: php, usability

Is there anyway to give text editors summary information in a tooltip for custom functions/classes etc. in the way that they can do for standard libraries while coding?

Failing this what is the standard way to highlight the purpose, required params etc. for a function/class in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [PHPDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/).

An example would be:

```
/**
 * Set the data
 *
 * @access public
 * @param string $field
 * @param mixed $value
 */
public function __set($field, $value)
{
  $this->_data[$field] = $value;
}

/**
 * Get the data
 *
 * @access public
 * @param string $field
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __get($field)
{
  return isset($this->_data[$field]) ? $this->_data[$field] : NULL;
}
```

As the comments self-explain, you use `@access` to show the visibility of the method (if the code being summarized is a method, of course), `@param`to show each parameter, and `@return` to show the type of the data being returned. There are many different tags to document many different aspects of the code.

Comment: And mentioning what editors do support the PHPDoc would be nice.

Comment: **@CodeCaster: The answer is: many** ;)

Quoted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc: _... Zend Studio, NetBeans, JetBrains PhpStorm, ActiveState Komodo Edit and IDE and Aptana Studio_ are using PHPDoc to _interpret variable types and other ambiguities_

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) standard for letting your IDE give you hints about, for example, a function.

Just before a function declaration you could have:

```
/**
 * This is a DocBlock comment
 */
function foo(){
    //....
}
```

I've used it in Netbeans and can say that it works quite nicely.